# delete or symlink with ^M in filename

Tags: bash, find

a bash script that used a Windows output file, generated me files and symlinks with ^M in the filename or link name.

when I do a `ls /var/bla` followed by a [tab] I see names like : file^M.pdf

when I do a `ls /var/bla` followed by a [enter] I see names like : file?.pdf

I would like to remove all of these files but a :

```
find /var/bla -name '*^M.*'
```

or

```
find /var/bla -name '*?.*'
```

do not give the attended results. the first case does not match anything and the second everything but not what I need.

Does anybody has an idea to remove these files?

Thanks by advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$'...'` to create a string using C-style escape sequences.

```
find /va/bla -name $'*\r*'
```

Comment: Thanks for the very fast solution !!! I was on the way but it would have take very very long time to get the right syntax